# __DIR__ not working for a php include

Tags: php, include

I am trying to use php includes to link one .php file to another. The structure is this:

```
ROOT
¦
+---templates
¦   ¦
¦   +---footer.php
¦
¦
+---main
    ¦
    +---maps
        ¦
        +---uk
            ¦
            +---map.php
```

Using `<?PHP include "../../../templates/navbar.php"; ?>` the code links absolutely fine.

Using either `<?PHP include dirname(__FILE__) . "../../../templates/navbar.php"; ?>`

or `<?PHP include __DIR__ . "../../../templates/navbar.php"; ?>` gets me absolutely nothing. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: __ DIR __ gives you the directory of the current php file. where did you put the include ?

Comment: Possibly you are missing [a quick look at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Before include echo text `echo __DIR__ . "../../../templates/navbar.php";` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

__DIR__ doesn't include the trailing `/` in directory name, so `<?PHP include __DIR__ . "/../../../templates/navbar.php"; ?>` is what you need.

Comment: brill - thanks a lot. this isn'y quite having the effect i intended though. i wanted to link multiple pages from different folders to footer.php, but not have to change the hrefs within footer.php to reflect where the include is coming from.